# getting an error:Access is denied on window.open() function in javascript

Tags: javascript

i am getting a problem while opening a file.
Here is my javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var refViewer = null;

function OpenViewerWindow(image) {
   alert(image)
   return window.open("file:///E:/HOBBYHOMES_E-PORTFOLIO/HobbyHomesWebApp/ePortfolio/PortFolioContent/5/ReferenceMaterial/"+image, "Viewer", "height=400px,width=550px,menubar=no,scrollbars=yes ,resizable=yes,top=100px,left=234px");
}


function openViewer(image) {

    if (refViewer != null) {
       if (refViewer.closed == false) {
            refViewer.close();
            refViewer = OpenViewerWindow(image);
        }
        else refViewer = OpenViewerWindow(image);
    }
    else
        refViewer = OpenViewerWindow(image);
}   
</script>
```

@item.candidateportfolo.FilePath contains the filename:prtf_1.docx

but my file is not opening.
In Internet Explorer i get Accesdenied Error.
In Mozilla Firfox it doesnot open
Am i specifying a wrong path.Please help me

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access local files through the browser, unless you have special privileges,or you are running the page locally (even then it won't work reliably across browsers)

Unless you use the HTML5 File API http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: @Jaun Mendes ya but wen i use Href it works like if i dont use my javascript and directly put href="filepath" in the anchor tag it opens the file

Comment: The problem is trying to access the window object for the window you created. You cannot use it because it's from a different domain.  Workaround, create a wrapper window that has an iframe in it

Answer (score 0):

YMMV but this registry setting works for my company's web application in terms of opening local (downloaded) Word documents:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Lockdown_Zones\0]
"2101"=dword:00000000
```